# PostgreSQL crashing: terminating connection due to unexpected postmaster exit

Tags: postgresql, parallel-processing, crash, postgresql-14

I am doing a datamigration task running 60 parallel processes from Python using Python threading.

After a while, PG crashes, see the end of the PG log file:

```
2021-11-17 09:30:09.973 CET [19372] FATAL:  terminating connection due to unexpected postmaster exit
2021-11-17 09:30:09.973 CET [17944] FATAL:  terminating connection due to unexpected postmaster exit
2021-11-17 09:30:09.973 CET [16628] FATAL:  terminating connection due to unexpected postmaster exit
2021-11-17 09:30:09.973 CET [19508] FATAL:  terminating connection due to unexpected postmaster exit
2021-11-17 09:30:09.973 CET [21636] FATAL:  postmaster exited during a parallel transaction
2021-11-17 09:30:09.973 CET [21636] CONTEXT:  SQL statement "......"
    PL/pgSQL function swn.nearest_pgr_node(geometry,numeric) line 7 at SQL statement
    SQL statement "select swn.nearest_pgr_node(structure_end_geom, 2.0)"
    PL/pgSQL function swn.migrate_cable(character varying) line 316 at SQL statement
2021-11-17 09:30:09.973 CET [21636] STATEMENT:  select swn.migrate_cable('{F97554BF-59BA-44D6-9D70-DD9B6B5927EA}')
2021-11-17 09:30:09.973 CET [17944] FATAL:  could not duplicate handle for "Global/PostgreSQL.2398935412": Permission denied
2021-11-17 09:30:11.227 CET [14284] FATAL:  terminating connection due to unexpected postmaster exit
```

Has anyone got a clue what the problem is? I am running this on a physical Windows server using local disk. PG version 14.

Thank you for any input. Googling the problem did not give me any usable hints.

The SQL code above (the "......") is

```
2021-11-17 09:30:09.973 CET [21636] CONTEXT:  SQL statement "with ptest as
                (
                    (select the_geom as point, id as id
                    from swn.pni_route_vertices_pgr
                    where st_distance(the_geom, _point) < _dist)
                )
                SELECT
    
                  closest_route.id                      FROM ptest p1
                CROSS JOIN LATERAL 
                  (SELECT
                      id, 
                      st_closestpoint(p2.point, _point) as nearest_point,
                      ST_Distance(_point, p2.point) as dist
                      FROM ptest p2
                   ORDER BY _point <-> p2.point
                     LIMIT 1
                   ) AS closest_route
                   order by 1"
    PL/pgSQL function swn.nearest_pgr_node(geometry,numeric) line 7 at SQL statement
    SQL statement "select swn.nearest_pgr_node(structure_end_geom, 2.0)"
    PL/pgSQL function swn.migrate_cable(character varying) line 316 at SQL statement
2021-11-17 09:30:09.973 CET [21636] STATEMENT:  select swn.migrate_cable('{F97554BF-59BA-44D6-9D70-DD9B6B5927EA}')
```

I have browsed through my PG log files looking for this error, and it turns out, that it is crashing every time on this very same code each time.

Extensions installed:

- pg_routing
- plpgsql
- postgis
- postgis_sfcgal
- uuid-ossp

Comment: if you create a subdirectory named crashdumps inside the cluster data directory it will generate crash dump under this folder. it can help to identify reason of the crash.

Comment: I fixed the question title, lest radical animal protectors take offence at "erminating connection".

Comment: You excluded the interesting SQL statement from the log. Please add the missing information and tell us which extensions are installed.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, I have updated the case with additional information

Answer (score 0):

The cause is that the postmaster, the parent process of all PostgreSQL processes, died unexpectedly.

For further clarification, check if there are other log messages that shed light on that event. You should also look into the kernel log for messages from the OOM killer. Very often, such events are caused by the system going out of memory while memory overcommit hasn't been deactivated (tune `vm.overcommit_memory` and `vm.overcommit_ratio`!).

I notice that your query is using PostGIS, which can consume a lot of memory when dealing with complicated geometries. Reduce `work_mem` and/or `shared_buffers` to avoid going out of memory.